# Retrieving Table Cell Values where one cell of each rown has an input box (JQUERY)

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

```
var values = [];

            $('#Route1 td').each(function () {
                //  values.push($(this).text());

                values.push($(this).html());

            });
```

In the above code I am trying to load all columns from a table into an array. However, one table cell of each row has an input box in it. How can I load the actual value of the textbox instead of loading the whole html .

The cell looks like as below.

```
    "<td><input type=text id=text1 value="I am input"/></td>"
```

The other problem I have is, even though I changed the value in the textbox, when I retrieve it from JQUERY it remains the same when the page is loaded the first time and does not take the latest value of the input box. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my answer in following

```
    $(".start").keyup(function(){
        $(this).closest('tr').find("input").each(function() {
             alert(this.value)
        });
    });
```

Although I ended up using a completely approach where I have links in my table and once clicked a popup with textbox appears and send value to the table data.